# How I can add another element on last output from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this simple array from my database:

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => John
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Alice
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Michael
        )
```

How I can add on last output (id 3) another value like this:

```
[2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Michael
            [age]     => 14
        )
```

Comment: something like `$arr[2]->age = 14;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array[count($array)-1]->age=14;
```

Comment: It's an object, not an array. Take a look at the comment from @Cid

Comment: You can with array_reverse but may give unexpected results